# Django - Variable inside style not detected

Tags: django, string, url

```
{% if photos %}

     {% for photo in photos %}

     {% endfor %}

{% else %}

  No images availble for the project.

{% endif %}
```

And I want to add a picture url inside the style tag.

```
div class='image-block col-sm-4' style="background: url({{photo}}) no-repeat center top;background-   size:cover;"
```

How can I get the {{photo}} url inside the string?

Comment: Can you show us Photo model too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try:

```
<div class='image-block col-sm-4' style="background: url("{{photo}}") no-repeat center top;background-size:cover;"></div>
```